# Runtime analysis of memoized recursive function

Tags: algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming

Code below computes if s1 can be reduced to t, if so how many ways. 
Let's say length of s1 is n and length of t is m. Worst case runtime of code below is O(n^m) without memoization. Say we can memoize sub-problems of s1, that substring recur. Runtime is O(m*n). Since we need to recur m times for each n. Is this reasoning correct?

```
static int distinctSeq(String s1, String t) {
    if (s1.length() == t.length()) {
        if (s1.equals(t))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        String ss = s1.substring(0, i)+ s1.substring(i + 1);
        count += distinctSeqRec(ss, t);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Could you elaborate?

Comment: Apologies, "... doesn't depend on `m`" was a mistake. However I don't think it is quite `n^m`: recurrence relation is `T(n, m) = O(m)` if `n = m`, and `T(n, m) = n * (O(n - 1) + T(n - 1, m))` otherwise. I believe this gives something of the form `O(n! / m!)` (ignoring off-by-one's).

Answer (score 0):

As @meowgoesthedog already mentioned your initial solution has a time complexity of `O(n!/m!)`:

- If you are starting with `s1` of length `n`, and `n > m` then you can go into `n` different states by excluding one symbol from the original string.
- You will continue doing it until your string has the length of `m`. The number of ways to come to the length of `m` from `n` using the given algorithm is `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*(m+1)`, which is effectively `n!/m!`
- For each string of length `m` formed by excluding symbols from initial string of length `n` you will have to compare string derived from `s1` and `t`, which will require `m` operations (length of the strings), so the complexity from the previous step should be multiplied by `m`, but considering that you have factorial in the big-O, another `*m` won't change the asymptotic complexity.

Now about the memoization. If you add memoization, then algorithm would transition only to states that weren't already visited, which means that the task is to count the number of unique substrings of `s1`. For simplicity we will consider that all symbols of `s1` are different. The number of states with length `x` is the number of ways of removing different `n-x` symbols from `s1` disregarding the order. Which is actually a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) - `C(n,x) = n!/((n-x)! * x!)`.

The algorithm will transition through all lengths between `n` and `m`, so overall time complexity would be `Sum(k=m...n, C(n,k)) = n!/((n-1)!*1!) + n!/((n-2)!*2! + ... + n!/((n-k)!*k!)`. Considering that we are counting asymptotic complexity we are interested in the largest member of that sum, which is the one with `k` as closest as possible to `n/2`. If `m` is lesser than `n/2`, then `C(n, n/2)` is present in the sum, otherwise `C(n,m)` is the largest element in it, so the complexity of the algorithm with memoization is `O(max(C(n,n/2), C(n,m)))`.